# Angular animations glitching

Tags: css, angularjs, animation

I am having problems implementing animations into angular. Animations are working however not as they should be.

Page transitions
I want to implement a smooth slide animation between pages using animate.css. When the animation is set up as follows:

```
.ng-leave           { 
   -webkit-animation: slideOutLeft 0.5s both ease-in;
   -moz-animation: slideOutLeft 0.5s both ease-in;
   animation: slideOutLeft 0.5s both ease-in;  z-index: 9999; }

.ng-enter           {
    animation: slideInRight 0.5s both ease-in; z-index: 8888; 
    -webkit-animation: slideInRight 0.5s both ease-in;
    -moz-animation: slideInRight 0.5s both ease-in; 
    }
```

What actually happens is that the enter animation never happens and the template/page is loaded below the leaving page as the leave animation is performed. This results is the loaded page 'snapping' into place rather than sliding in as the other page leaves.

Hide/Show
Again this happens with the hide and show directive. The enter animation never happens and the newly visible element snaps into place once the leave animation has finished.

Any idea?